# Modifiy jwt token in java

Tags: java, json, token, jwt

I use jwt web token for changing clients password. I have a custome field in claims and i want to change this field when client click on the link. The value of field is change with
 claims.replace(IS_CLICKED_TOKEN_PARAM, Boolean.TRUE);

I do this in a method and it works in the method but the value globale is not changed.
I dont understand, can we modifiy a jwt token?

Thanks and sorry for my bad english

Comment: I do not understand your flow. You want to change the JWT in client side and send it to server, or issue a new JWT in server side after client clicks?

Comment: what framework are you using to execute `claims.replace(IS_CLICKED_TOKEN_PARAM, Boolean.TRUE);` Post the details if you want an accurate answer

Comment: Thank you @ pedrofb . I use **io.jsonwebtoken** for java. And i want to invalidate or change a cliam value but i read some threads concernant this issue and it is not possible to invalidate jwt token manually.  I found an other solution: Iicreated an map of tokens valides and i remove token from map to invalidate the token.